# Error using pygraphviz on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: osx-lion, graphviz, pygraphviz

After some struggle installing pygraphviz on Mac OSX Lion **([sudo] easy_install pygraphviz)** I've tried to use it, but it crashes when I import it. Here you can see the error.

Any idea to solve it? Do I should install another aux library...?

```
>>> import pygraphviz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygraphviz/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from agraph import AGraph, Node, Edge, Attribute, ItemAttribute
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 19, in <module>
    import graphviz as gv
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygraphviz/graphviz.py", line 7, in <module>
    import _graphviz
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygraphviz/_graphviz.so, 2): Symbol not found: _Agundirected
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygraphviz/_graphviz.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

Comment: I would suggest looking at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727619/tclstub-issue-while-using-homebrew-to-install-graphviz].