# tclstub issue while using homebrew to install graphviz

Tags: macos, tcl, homebrew, graphviz, tk-toolkit

Homebrew quits when trying to install graphviz,

```
CCLD   libtcldot_builtin.la
ld: library not found for -ltclstub8.6
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[4]: *** [libtcldot.la] Error 1
make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
ld: library not found for -ltclstub8.6
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[4]: *** [libtcldot_builtin.la] Error 1
make[3]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

an issue seems to be that this particular library is not the one installed on the machine,

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.4/libtclstub8.4.a
/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/libtclstub8.5.a
/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/libtclstub8.5.a
/usr/lib/libtclstub8.5.a
```

it looks around the net like a decent amount of people are running into trouble trying to install graphviz with homebrew.  There solutions however seem to not work for me.

Comment: this is the error that seems to be halting the process:

ld: library not found for -ltclstub8.6

However, a locate reveals:

/usr/lib/libtclstub8.6.a
/usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.0/lib/libtclstub8.6.a

Could someone please help me with this, or at least provide some good/usefull reference.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465258/xlib-h-not-found-when-building-graphviz-on-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion

and 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123751/graphviz-and-brew-doctor-unexpected-dylibs-error/12164207#12164207

DO NOT address my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550971/tcltk-library-issue-while-install-rcmdr-package-on-macbookpro), it seems like

```
remove tcl-tk
brew -v install tcl-tk --with-tk
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.0/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.0/lib/libtk8.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libtclstub8.5.a /usr/lib/libtclstub8.6.a
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libtkstub8.5.a /usr/lib/libtkstub8.6.a
brew update
brew upgrade
brew -v reinstall graphviz
```

does the trick.  The last two linking where done as suggested [here](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/19664).  I hope this helps other folks.

Comment: Heads up to those who've made the switch to 10.11 (El Capitan) - this won't work since rootless was introduced. Will come back with a solution if I find one.

Answer (score 3):

The package seems to have moved recently:

```
brew install homebrew/dupes/tcl-tk
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.0/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.0/lib/libtk8.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libtclstub8.5.a /usr/lib/libtclstub8.6.a
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libtkstub8.5.a /usr/lib/libtkstub8.6.a
brew reinstall graphviz
```