# TclTk library issue while install Rcmdr package on MacBookPro

Tags: r, macos, tcl, graphviz, tk-toolkit

I get the following ERROR while trying to load Rcmdr for R on my MacBook Pro:

```
> library("Rcmdr")
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so, 10): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rcmdr’
```

I have other problem on this machine related to the TclTk libraries, but I didn't get any help when I posted about troubles installing [graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727619/tclstub-issue-while-using-homebrew-to-install-graphviz).

If someone could help me fix the TclTk library issue I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like there is no file `/usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib`…

Comment: agreed.  not in that dir.
    locate libtcl8.6.dylib
    /usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.0/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib

Comment: you marked as duplicate the older of the two questions???

@thomas could you help me understand how a question that was asked (and aswered) in 2013 is the duplicate of one that was asked in 2014?!?!?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank your @donal-fellows !

The solutions was to put symlinks to the libs where R expected them:

```
brew remove tcl-tk
brew -v install tcl-tk --with-tk
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.0/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.0/lib/libtk8.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib
```

let us now hope that this fixes my graphviz issue!